# Why is there a round indent in the plastic packaging tray that's inside the box for the iPad Pro 9.7?

Tags: ipad

I just bought an iPad Pro 9.7. Inside the iPad's box, in the plastic packaging tray that the iPad rests in, there's a small round indent, about the size of a small watch battery. Since everything that Apple does seems to be purposefully designed, I assume there's a reason for the indent, but I'm stumped. Does anyone know why it's there?

You can see it in the second photo down in this iLounge review:
http://www.ilounge.com/index.php/news/comments/unboxing-the-new-9.7-inch-ipad-pro

Answer (score 1):

On the fifth picture down in the same link, the camera is shown to be protruding out from the iPad.  I would say it could be for that.

Without actually seeing it, i couldn't be for sure, but does the camera fit into that hole?